# jQuery ajax(): can't process response

Tags: ajax, jquery, httpresponse

I'm trying to process the response body of an ajax call from jQuery but so far no success.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
function doAjaxClosedStatus(url, requestId, closedStatusId) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : url+requestId,
    data : ({
        'closedStatusId' : closedStatusId
    })
}).success(function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    if (msg == "fail") {
        alert("test");
        $(document).append($('<div class="alert alert-error affix" data-offset-top="200">You can\'t specify a closed status if status is not set as "closed"</div>'));
        $('option:selected', '.closedStatus ').removeAttr('selected');
        $('.closedStatus option:first-child').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

}

So the whole call and server-side processing is working like a charm and responding with either "done" or "fail", respectively when everything went right or wrong (I know you guessed it). Now I'd like to do some client-side processing when the response is **fail**, but `alert(msg)` is never triggered... **What am I doing wrong?**

**EDIT**: I forgot to say, I'm using Spring MVC as backend and I'm just returning "fail" as `@ResponseBody`. When I check the network flow the response body is "fail" or "done".

**EDIT2**: I tried with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : url+requestId,
    data : ({
        'closedStatusId' : closedStatusId
    }),
    success:function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        if (msg == "fail") {
            alert("test");
            $(document).append($('<div class="alert alert-error affix" data-offset-top="200">You can\'t specify a closed status if status is not set as "closed"</div>'));
            $('option:selected', '.closedStatus ').removeAttr('selected');
            $('.closedStatus option:first-child').prop('selected', 'selected');
        }
    }   
});
```

Still no success...

**EDIT3**:
So I've been trying this again:

```
function doAjaxClosedStatus(url, requestId, closedStatusId) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : url+requestId,
    data : ({
        'closedStatusId' : closedStatusId
    }),
    success:function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        if (msg == "fail") {
            alert("test");
            $(document).append($('<div class="alert alert-error affix" data-offset-top="200">You can\'t specify a closed status if status is not set as "closed"</div>'));
            $('option:selected', '.closedStatus ').removeAttr('selected');
            $('.closedStatus option:first-child').prop('selected', 'selected');
        }
    }   
});
```

}

And for some reason, it does work now. Maybe that was because my browser's cache not being emptied and thus working with an older version of my script. Anyway, now this is working correctly. Except for my DOM manipulations, but this doesn't belong to the question itself so subject closed! Thanks everyone!

Comment: << Maybe that was because my browser's cache not being emptied >> This would explain all ;)

Comment: ^^^^^  Happens to us all, post it as an answer yourself -> "Stupid me didn't hit CTRL-F5", and accept it, and you'll get some more rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't chain `success`, it's a method within $.ajax, you're probably thinking of `done()`

```
function doAjaxClosedStatus(url, requestId, closedStatusId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : url+requestId,
        data : {closedStatusId : closedStatusId}
    }).done(function(msg) {
        if ( $.trim(msg) == "fail") {
            alert("test");
            $(document).append($('<div class="alert alert-error affix" data-offset-top="200">You can\'t specify a closed status if status is not set as "closed"</div>'));
            $('option:selected', '.closedStatus ').removeAttr('selected');
            $('.closedStatus option:first-child').prop('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried with done() before, still no result, I just changed to success() for the sake of trying, my bad.

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser - with what version of jQuery ?

Comment: success of jqXhr is deprecated but not removed so OP's code should work the same with done()

Comment: @roasted Request is sent correctly, server-side processing is done correctly, and using network tab I can see the response is received with body being either "done" or "fail".

Comment: Ya, just saw your edit in question so adeneo code should work and yours too

Comment: @roasted - true, `success` is not removed, but it's still not chainable with a deferred object like `done()`, which was introduced in 1.7 (I think), that's why I asked the version.

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser - Try it like this, and tell us what you get in the console -> http://jsfiddle.net/pEFsx/1/ .......

Comment: @adeneo following some tests i see success can be chained so maybe something i'm missing.  http://jsfiddle.net/MCZcW/  but for sure .done() is preferred

Comment: @roasted - seems to work, didn't know that? They must have added it to avoid errors when using the wrong methods/functions.

Comment: @adeneo Your jsfiddle version is working, I'm logging and even alert()'ing either "done" or "fail". I'm trying some stuff because the errors might actually come from my DOM stuff in the if (msg=="fail").

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser - did you try trimming, like in the answer above ?

Comment: See EDIT3 for more info (coming in a few secs)

Comment: I suggest one of you post an answer with what's in EDIT3 and I'll accept this. Thanks for your help, both of you!

Comment: Well, I accepted this answer since it works and you kept helping me through the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var request = $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url : url+requestId,
     data : ({'closedStatusId' : closedStatusId});

request.done(function(msg) {
     alert("yes");
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
     alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

This is what works for me

Comment: It's strange because this code should work in any case using fail & done

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it didn't work either. As I said, maybe my cache wasn't emptied correctly (using ctrl+R) and thus I was working with an older version of my script :(

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like .success function is outside the $.ajax .

It should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : url+requestId,
    data : ({
        'closedStatusId' : closedStatusId
    }),
.success(function(data) {
    alert(data);
    if (data == "fail") {
        alert("test");
        $(document).append($('<div class="alert alert-error affix" data-offset-top="200">You can\'t specify a closed status if status is not set as "closed"</div>'));
        $('option:selected', '.closedStatus ').removeAttr('selected');
        $('.closedStatus option:first-child').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

and also make sure that your server sends some data.. in case of php echo the result.

Comment: I think `function(data)` should have been `function(msg)`.

Comment: Well, simply the .success method cannot be inside ajax, at least not in this form. I'm editing my answer to add more info

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works for me as is, but I have some theories for why it could fail.

1. The mime type of the response could lead jquery to misinterpret the response as XML (for example) and then fail to parse it. You could fix that by hardcoding the `dataType`.

   ```
   dataType : 'text',
   ```
2. You are trying to connect to a server on a different domain so you're getting a cross browser scripting error. You can fix that by setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server. One way would be via the .htaccess file like this.

   ```
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   ```